# adding a functionality to a class python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to add a functionality to a class, without changing its behavior. But it gives an AttributeError. How do I code this? (PS: You don't need to know `praw` for this)

---

In the following: the `Comment` object is returned from `Reddit` object.

```py
from praw import Reddit
from praw.models import Comment

class Comment(Comment):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("this is my Comment")
        
    def is_awesome(self):
        return True
        
class Reddit(Reddit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("this is my Reddit")

# this is my Reddit object
reddit = Reddit("some args")

# this is a Comment object from praw 
k = reddit.comment(id="hzfbs3e")

# this gives an `AttributeError`
k.is_awesome()

# for example there is also this
k.author # which returns a `Redditor` object
```

Comment: You didn't modify the `Comment` class; you created another class also called `Comment`. `k` is an instance of the original class `Comment`, not your class.

Comment: The [linked dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/972/3890632) shows how to add a method to a class (among other options).

Comment: It seems you are calling a function `is_awesome` that is defined in the class `Comment`.

You don't extend the class as you should, the class `Reddit` should take `Comment` as an argument.